# Dan Kegel's crosstool is out of date -- does anyone know of a fix?

Tags: gcc, gnu

My company does Linux embedded systems using Freescale PowerPC processors.

Some years back I wrote an internal HowTo on how to use [Dan Kegel's crosstool](http://kegel.com/crosstool/) to set up a cross compiler environment for our product.  I hadn't touched it since then but I recently tried it and found it doesn't work.   The scripts look for files on redhat.com's ftp server that are currently not there.

The latest cross tool script is the one I am using, version 0.43.

So before I roll up my sleeves and see if I can fix it myself, I am wondering if someone has already done this.  Does anyone here know Kegel well enough to contact him and ask if he is planning to do an update?  (My guess is not.  He works at Google now.)

Alternatively, is there a better GNU cross tool builder than Kegel's cross tool?  It might be easier to switch over than to update the old one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out Mr. Kegel was kind enough to respond to my e-mail.  It turns out his original scripts have been picked up by an open-source group that calls it [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/).  They did an amazing amount of work on this and the tool now uses a curses-based menu system to select the options for the cross development to generate.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for file names directly in Google (try '<filename> site:ftp.redhat.com' or something similar), and often results will yield revised links to the files. If that is the problem, it should just be a case of cut and paste. Alternately, I would recommend downloading the files locally, modifying the script to see them there and then bundling them with the script.

Kegel left Google for a startup. His resume is at http://www.kegel.com/resume.html . Have you tried emailing him? He might just respond.

Comment: I didn't see that page so I didn't se his e-mail address.  So I assumed he didn't want to be contacted.   I'll give that a try thanks.